How to filter SAP Data at source with Synapse/ADF CDC?
In Azure Synapse I'm using the SAP CDC Connector to connect to a S/4HANA system. My goal is to filter data on the source side before storing it in my ADLS Gen2, as there are certain data restrictions that I need to adhere to.
I need to fetch multiple objects from SAP, and I typically use a parameterized approach for this. I have a JSON file that contains parameters and queries for each object I want to retrieve from the source. For instance, I define SQL queries in the JSON file to perform the filtering. This method works well with SQL Connectors.
However, with the SAP CDC Connector, I haven’t been able to find any functionality that allows me to apply such filtering directly at the source.
What I tried so far:
I’m currently using a dataflow in a for each loop. I tried to pass dynamic column & row value names in the Filter panel of the dataflow. However, I did not manage put in dynamic column values. In the dataflow I even "chained" filters with different column names & value filters, however, this did not work as I need different filter values for different objects that I pass through the dataflow.
I wish I could pass SQL queries (or similar, like it is an option in other connectors), but with CDC Connector Im stuck with the expression builder. I cannot figure out how to dynamically pass query like filtering. So Im just getting the unfiltered objects, which is not an option. I have so many objects, that I cant maintain a non parameterized version.
I tried using a copy data activity as well, however when selecting it, I do not get the option to choose the SAP CDC Integration Dataset. Is a CDC Linked Service disabled for a copy data activity?

can you please provide the info on what you have tried so far?

Hi, I edited the question so it is hopefully more clear. Please let me know if you need more information or clarifying
